# Already using mysql_connect--should I also use mysqli_connect?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First, some background: I am working on a pre-2000 website that uses `mysql_connect` and `mysql_*` functions everywhere. It is not feasible to simply replace all of these at the moment.

I do, however, plan on slowly making the change to `mysqli_*` functions. I have run into an instance where I need to use `mysqli_multi_query` though, and was wondering if it would be better to:

1. Create a function that opens and closes the mysqli connection, while performing one mysqli_multi_query.
2. Create a function that opens a mysqli connection when needed, and only open the mysqli connection only on pages that need it.
3. Simply use the `mysqli_connect()` function the same way I am using the `mysql_connect()` function and have both connect at the beginning of my scripts and close at the end, on all pages.

The trouble I am having with deciding on these is that **1** limits the number of multi-queries I can do on one page (while also adding to the future code-cleanup that needs to be done), **2** also adds to the code-cleanup, albeit not quite as much as **1**, and **3** might be either inefficient, or unsafe, although I would be able to clean-up as I run into the old queries.

This website gets over 1 million visitors per month.

Anyone know what would be "best-practice" in this scenario?

Comment: "In the footer, use a conditional that checks if the mysqli connection is open, and closes it if it is." All connections close at request end automatically so you don't need this.

Comment: I think for the sake of maintainability and abstraction, using some sort of wrapper function or class for database interaction is the way to go. so next time when you want to change something, you only edit in one place not 30. This will also help when you eventually update the rest of the site, as you could just change all the mysql_connect() calls to a call to your db wrapper instead.

Comment: @DigitalChris Thanks, edited accordingly.

Comment: @jammypeach So are you suggesting **2**, or a combination of **2** and **3**?

Comment: @user3191820 I suppose I'm leaning towards *2*, yes. I'd say *3* would make more work for you, were you to need to change things again.

Comment: @jammypeach While I appreciate the suggestion, the main question I'm asking is what the "best practice" is for having multiple mysql connections. I suppose I can just knock off **1**, but is it fine to have 2 connections open on all pages, or should I do an as-needed approach? (All pages need at least 1 connection, just FYI). I'll be using the wrapper function whether **2** or **3** is the better choice, so thanks for that.

Comment: @user3191820 "best practice" being arguably a matter of opinion, mine is that 2 is the better choice. I would say that whether or not to open connections when they are not strictly required is a judgement call for you to make - if your servers are fast enough that the extra connection latency makes no noticable differnece to load speed, then just open both on every page. If it adds >2 seconds then only open them when you need them. I say it's a better choice because the abstraction makes code more manageable and maintainable in the future, for you and for other devs.

Comment: @jammypeach Sounds good. If you can turn this into an answer that'll help others when they come across this page, I'll accept it as the answer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: @user3191820 - a downvote prodded me to think about my answer, I realised it was mostly based on opinion and offered no real references to back up what I said. I've edited the answer quite substantially, please review and decide if my answer is still the correct answer for your question, and unmark as accepted if it is not. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"best practice" seems to be to use PDO for your MySQL connections, according to recent articles turned up during a search on the topic (for example https://phpbestpractices.org/#mysql ) although I couldn't find any specific guidance on when to open those connections if they are not strictly required on that page.

I'd suggest going with your second choice, as the abstraction makes code more manageable and maintainable in the future, for you and for other devs. As far as I know, there is no specific drawback to using `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions side-by-side, and it is recommended to use `mysqli_*` over `mysql_*` in all cases 
( see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php, the section under 'recommended API').

However your code will not be as secure as it could be until you complete the transition.

I would say that whether or not to open connections when they are not strictly required is a judgement call for you to make - I'd lean towards only opening it when you need it on general principles of efficiency, however in practice when dealing with legacy code it may prove far more trouble than it's worth. If it doesn't slow your server down too much you could live with it, so long as you recognise it's not the most efficient way to go.

Comment: @downvoter, care to leave any feedback? I'd like to improve this answer if I can but not certain what isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

PHP offers three different APIs to connect to MySQL: mysql(outdated), mysqli, and PDO extensions.

You don't need to connect to the database on every request.

```
mysqli_connect() with p: host prefix
//or
PDO::__construct() with PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT as a driver option
```

http://www.php.net/mysql_pconnect

In your case, I would use PDO type connection implemented as the singleton pattern with "permanent" connection options.

Included on top of the every script.

```
class Database {
    private static $instance;
    private $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
    private $user = 'dbuser';
    private $password = 'dbpass';


    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = 
               new PDO($this->dsn, 
                       $this->user, 
                       $this->password, 
                       array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT)
               );
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

That way you can get database instance with:

```
Database::getInstance();
```

...and don't flame me for using singletons in the legacy app! ;)

Comment: Why would you recommend PDO over mysqli?

Comment: Simply because it is an abstraction and thus isn't coupled to a particular database type and it also provides a nice way to prevent SQL injections.